# Error When Using UIApplication sharedApplication?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Obviously, I'm new to iOS development, but I could really use somebody's help. I am building a tab bar application in which I am attempting to load .plists into drill-down table views. The problem is that I can't seem to get this method right, as I am trying to use the navigation controller for a tab in its ViewController. I'm positive that my error is in the second line.

```
A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
AppDelegate.indNavControl *indNavControl;
```

Subsequently, I get some errors. Here is the code, and I'll point out where the errors are:

```
    if([Children count] == 0) {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];//Property "indNavControl" not found on object of type "IndustriesViewController"
    [dvController release];
}
else {

    //Prepare to tableview.
    IndustriesViewController *indViewControl = [[IndustriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndustryView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Increment the Current View
    indViewControl.CurrentLevel += 1;

    //Set the title;
    indViewControl.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:indViewControl animated:YES]; //Property "indNavControl" not found on object of type "IndustriesViewController"

    indViewControl.tableDataSource = Children;

    [indViewControl release];
}
```

}

Just to be clear, I have imported the header file of my App Delegate. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've read your code a coupe of times and I don't understand it. Specifically `AppDelegate.indNavControl *indNavControl;` - is that legal? and what is it trying to do? Secondly, from your error it would appear that the second block of code comes from a IndustriesViewController and that class does not have a indNavControl property. I cannot see how these two sections of code relate or why you need to go after the app delegate. You also appear to be trying to alloc a IndustriesNavController from within a IndustriesNavController. Or am I missing something? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line *`AppDelegate.indNavControl *indNavControl;`* is wrong. I think you don't need this line at all. And while pushing new view controller you can directly use *AppDelegate.indNavControl* instead of *self.indNavControl*,

```
[AppDelegate.indNavControl pushViewController:...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your theory that the problem is in the second line is correct.

```
AppDelegate.indNavControl *indNavControl;
```

that line isn't really doing anything. You need a class where `AppDelegate.indNavControl` is.

You have a couple of options:

1) if you want indViewControl to be a 'public' property

```
* in your IndustriesViewController.h, move the declaration of indViewControl there.

@interface
{
    WhateverClass *indNavControl;
}

@property (retain) WhateverClass*indNavControl;
@end
```

2) if you want a private property then add an empty category at the top of your .m with the ivar and property declaration from above.

What the compiler is complaining about is trying to access a property that doesn't exist.

calling `self.whateverIvar` requires an `@property` definition.

Answer (score 0):

first create the instance of the appdelegate like and then you can access, whatever variables you have declared in appdelegate as property,synthesize.There is no need to create seperate variable of indNavControl.